# Loading screen in j2me

Tags: java-me

I want loading screen in my application such that it appear when the internet connection starts and loading screen get hide when I got the data from webservice.

I had tried to use .gif file. It is working properly in the simple application which I made which shows only .gif file. But when I integrate this code with my applicationj it is showing the error.

The error is:

```
TRACE: <at java.lang.IllegalArgumentException>, Exception caught in Display class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(), bci=8
        at com.semaphore.GifCanvas.<init>(GifCanvas.java:41)
        at com.semaphore.CompanySplashScreen.dismiss(CompanySplashScreen.java:89)
        at com.semaphore.CompanySplashScreen.keyPressed(CompanySplashScreen.java:78)
        at javax.microedition.lcdui.CanvasLFImpl.uCallKeyPressed(), bci=19
        at javax.microedition.lcdui.DisplayableLFImpl.uCallKeyEvent(), bci=146
        at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display$DisplayEventConsumerImpl.handleKeyEvent(), bci=30
        at com.sun.midp.lcdui.DisplayEventListener.process(), bci=277
        at com.sun.midp.events.EventQueue.run(), bci=179
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

the code which i am using to for executing .gif file is:-

```
InputStream ins = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/loading.gif");
        try {
            player = Manager.createPlayer(ins, "image/gif");
             player.prefetch();
             player.setLoopCount(10);

        player.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MediaException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if ((vidc = (VideoControl) player.getControl("VideoControl")) != null)
        vidc.initDisplayMode(VideoControl.USE_DIRECT_VIDEO, this);
        try {
            vidc.setDisplayLocation(2, 2);
            vidc.setDisplaySize(getWidth()/2,getHeight()/2);
        }
        catch (MediaException me) {}
        vidc.setVisible(true);
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/mm/jsr135/javax/microedition/media/Manager.html#createPlayer%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29), your InputStream is null.
Check if you have your resource properly placed.  With that path, it should be on the root dir of your project (or the src dir, I'm not sure). But just check it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i got the solution.But now the problem is my code is working properly in simulater.but not working properly in sony erricsonT700 device.Can u plz explain me why it is not executing in device.I had tried to find out this in sonyerricson forum but can't get any solution.Please help me if u have the solution

Comment: @shweta there are plenty of reasons why is not working... you need to give some more details